# How to install an Office Addin to all computers in an organization

Tags: installation, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

We have developed an addin for Word 2016 (relevant for 2013 as well) which consists of a manifest.xml and a web project serving html and javascript. We want to distribute this addin to all the users in an organization.

We do not have any trouble setting up the webservice and pointing the manifest to it, however the issue is distributing the xml and installing it into the Word instances on user's computers.

What is the simplest way for an organization admin to inject this addin into users Word applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered [centralized deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment)?

The Office 365 admin center makes it easy for an administrator to deploy Office Add-ins to users and groups within their organization. Add-ins deployed via the admin center are available to users in their Office applications right away, with no client configuration required. You can use Centralized Deployment to deploy internal add-ins as well as add-ins provided by ISVs.

Comment: The problem is that I do not control how organizations manage their Office installations.
We have multiple organizations as clients and we need to provide the addin to all of them.

Some will have Office 365, some Office 2016 and 2013 installations.

How do we go about it? Should I just tell them to figure it out and give the manifest.xml ?

Comment: You could alternatively [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-the-office-store) your solution to AppSource.

Comment: We do not really want to make it public and besides there will have to be slightly different content per organization, so there would be many different addins for each organization.
Even if I publish it there, what is the process to make it available for all employees in a given organization? Or would they have to initiate it individually?
Perhaps it makes more sense to put the addin manifest in a trusted location per organization and somehow make all the users pick it up? However, how does one do it?

Comment: @dvitonis Not my area of expertise at all, but since there's been no follow-up: The docs offer a third approach: Sharepoint catalog https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish-task-pane-and-content-add-ins-to-an-add-in-catalog. Then it wouldn't matter whether clients use Office 365 or a local setup.exe version of Office.

Comment: Thank you @CindyMeister, we will certainly consider it though I see 2 issues with it:
1. Required sharepoint
2. Users need to initiate addin insertion themselves